# Convert Categorical features to Numerical

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, data-science, categorical

I have a lot of categorical columns  and want  to convert values in those columns to numerical values so that I will be able to apply ML model.

Now by data looks something like below.

Column 1- Good/bad/poor/not reported
column 2- Red/amber/green
column 3- 1/2/3
column 4- Yes/No

Now I have already assigned numerical values of 1,2,3,4 to good, bad, poor, not reported in column 1 .

So, now can I give the same numerical values like 1,2,3 to red,green, amber etc in column 2 and in a similar fashion to other columns or will doing that confuse model when I implement it

Comment: you could factorize: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html or you could make categories: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for some of the rated columns by using df[colname].map({})or LabelEncoder() .
They will change each categorical data to numbers, so there is a weight between them, which means if poor is one and good is 3, as you can see, there is a difference between them. You want the model to know it, but if it's just something like colors, you know there is no preference in colors, and green is no different from blue .so it is better not to use the same method and use get_dummies in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

The colour values you mention are nominal. There is no ranking or order to these values. If you assign 1,2,3 etc the data can be misrepresented as being from a scale.

To avoid this you can transform them by using the onehotencoder technique. This effectively encodes a multi value categorical field into the following:

```
red = 100
amber = 010
green = 001
```

You can use the following library from sk-learn.preprocessing:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this idea of using one-hot encoding to colors will be very helpful. Also what I would like to know is if can I assign 1 & 2 to 'YES' & 'NO' in 'column 4'. OR shall I not do it as 1&2 are already present in 'column 3' plus I have also given 1,2,3,4 to Good/bad/poor/not reported  to 'column 1'  .

Comment: For the values yes and no, 0 & 1 is fine. You can use a label encoder from sk-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html. For column 3 ordinal is fine as poor could be seen as 1 and good 3 etc. There is a ranking system in place. It doesn't matter about other columns having the same values as the algorithm discerns between them.